# Cantor-like set removing middle-$\alpha$ open intervals

Tags: general-topology

If I change the construction of the Cantor set, meaning that I will not remove the middle-third open interval but rather the middle-$\alpha$ open interval with length $0<\alpha<1$. For example, if I chose to remove the middle-$\frac{1}{7}$ open interval.

Here a picture of three consecutive steps:
[image: Cantor-like set with removed 1/7-open intervals]

So every closed interval has a length smaller than $\frac{1}{2^n}$ in the n-th step of constructing it. Does such an construction result in a set with measure $0$?

Comment: Not necessarily; it depends on how much is removed.  The general construction is sometimes called a "fat Cantor set": 

http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/labs/paperfoldinglab/fatcantorset.html

Comment: @StrangerLoop You might want to reconsider. Fat Cantor sets are still a further generalization.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does, and for the same reason: the total length sum of the intervals at the $n$-th step forms a sequence which converges to zero. For the middle thirds Cantor set that sequence is $\left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n$. For your middle sevenths Cantor set that sequence is $\left( \frac{6}{7} \right)^n$, and for general $\alpha$ that sequence is $(1-\alpha)^n$.

Comment: I got the result $(1-\alpha)^n$ but I think I made the mistake contemplating at $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-\alpha)^k$ instead of just $(1-\alpha)^n$.